# GeoExt printPage cannot handle WFS vector features

Tags: wfs, geoext, printing

I recently added the print function to my GeoExt web application, using

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities"></script>
```

to define the printCapabilities variable,

```
        var printProvider = new GeoExt.data.PrintProvider({
            method: "GET", 
            url: "localhost/geoserver/pdf", 
            capabilities: printCapabilities
        });
```

for the print provider and within the mapPanel

```
bbar: ["->", {
                text: "Print...",
                handler: function() { 
                    var printDialog = new Ext.Window({
                            items: [new GeoExt.PrintMapPanel({
                                sourceMap: mapPanel,
                                printProvider: printProvider,
                                    listeners: {
                                    "loadcapabilities": function() {
                                    var printPage = new GeoExt.data.PrintPage({
                                        printProvider: printProvider,
                                        customParams: {
                                            mapTitle: "LVR WebGIS",
                                            comment: "created with GeoExt"
                                        }
                                    });
                                        printPage.fit(mapPanel, true);
                                        printProvider.print(mapPanel, printPage);
                                    }
                                    },

                                })
                            ],
                         bbar: [{
                                text: "Create PDF",
                                handler: function() {
                                    printDialog.items.get(0).print();
                                }
                            }]
                    });
                printDialog.show();
                }
            }],
```

to add the function to my mapPanel. Regarding this, I have two issues to be solved:

1.) the printPage popping up does not contain anything but the button saying "Create PDF". There should be a preview of the map to print, right?

2.) when some WFS vector features are displayed in the map, the print function does not work properly anymore. It opens a new tab in my browser but does not create the PDF. Instead, the new tab is left about:blank.

What am I doing wrong here? Is the information I provided enough for you guys to help me solve the problem? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? We are having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the print provider set up refer to localhost:8080 instead of localhost/ ? if they really are on different ports then you probably need a proxy to handle the same origin requirements.

Comment: Well, it seem as this would help in one way: the new tab opening is not blank but is leading to this terribly long URL: 

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf?spec=%7B%22units%22%3A%22degrees%22%2C%22srs%22%3A%22EPSG%3A4326%22%2C%22layout%22%3A%22A4%22%2C%22dpi%22%3A380%2C%22layers%22%3A%5B%7B%22baseURL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wms.nrw.de%2Fgeobasis%2FDOP_JPG%3F%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A1%2C%22singleTile%22%3Afalse%2C%22type%22%3A%22WMS` and so on, it basically lists each feature in the map with it´s parameters. Something loads but stops after a while, not creating any output.